# Can't pass a string literal to my function

Tags: c++

My function header is

```
int display_caption( char* caption ); 

if( display_caption( "hybrid thresholded Image" ) != 0 ) 
{ 
    return 0; 
}
```

It returns an error

> Argument of type 'const char*' is incompatible with parameter of type 'char*'

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: You cannot convert a pointer from `const T*` to `T*`. `display_caption` is likely meant to have a `const char*` parameter instead of a `char*`.

Comment: Try `int display_caption(const char* caption)`.

Comment: Or even better, considering how you're using it: `bool display_caption(const char* caption);`.

Comment: What do you understand about your error?  Have you identified your argument?  Have you identified your parameter?  Do you see how they are incompatible?  As it stands, this question is asking us to guess what you don't understand about that message.

Answer (score 0):

If `display_caption` doesn't need to modify the `caption` parameter, you can change its type to `const char*` :

```
int display_caption( const char* caption );
```

if it does need to modify it, you will need to make a copy of the string first.